# How do I update Apportable build targets?

Tags: apportable

When first run Apportable generates a bunch of stuff, in `ProjectName.approj/`, which includes some stuff generated from the Xcode project targets.

I have changed my Xcode project's bundle identifier (I need the generated APK to have a certain package name, and that seems to come from the bundle identifier) but the Apportable generated builds still have the old package name. I think this is related to the build targets stuff it generates.

How do I update this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding `--generate` to the `apportable` command will cause the xcode project to be reparsed.